# Ensure library registration code is called only once before use

Tags: c#, static-constructor

I'm using a third party library, and as part of its requirements, I need to register a license key to it, before using it.

To help do this, I was thinking of having a helper class of form:

```
namespace SomeLibrary
{
    public static class LibraryHelper
    {
        public static void RegisterLicense()
        {
        }

        static LibraryHelper()
        {
            // call underlying library's code to register. Should only be called once.
            TheThirdPartyLibrary.RegisterLicenceKey("ABC");  
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the startup of my application (e.g. in Program.cs), I could call:

```
SomeLibrary.LibraryHelper.RegisterLicense().
```

The static constructor is just to ensure that  `TheThirdPartyLibrary.RegisterLicenceKey("ABC");`
does not get called more than once. My understanding is that this should work, but the code looks a bit unusual having a RegisterLicense method that is empty.
Are there any other alternatives ?

Comment: Can't you just call `TheThirdPartyLibrary.RegisterLicenceKey("ABC");` once at your application entry point?

Comment: yes, that would be the expected general pattern of use. I was thinking to use a static constructor, just to try to make it more robust. Maybe it's overkill.